# Safe version of popen()?

Tags: c, process, fork, subprocess, pipe

I use fork()/exec()/wait() rather than system() when the command has user input as some of its arguments so the user can't put something like...

```
&rm -rf /home/* && echo HAHA
```

... as an argument.

I'm assuming popen is as dangerous as system() because it takes a single string and not a list of strings like the exec family of functions do.

I can only get the return value from the exec functions though.  Is there a "safe" version of popen that I can run with user input and process stdout / stderr back in the parent process?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The safe way is to set up the necessary pipes yourself, using straight `pipe()` calls directly.

That's what `popen()` does under the hood, but it also invokes the shell in order to run the child process. Skipping that step should make it safer.

Comment: +1 Yes, just take a look at the popen source code (for example here: http://www.cse.lehigh.edu/~brian/course/2011/cunix/notes/ch11/popen.c)

Comment: @Adriano, nice... thanks.  You too unwind.  Looks like popen already uses execl; I'll probably just copy it but pass in the arguments as a null terminated va_list or char* [] and call execv rather than execl.